# Exibir um resultado espefico para uma busca com condição. SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, db2

Olá, tudo bem? Eu possuo uma tabela que tem um NP(numero de produçao) e cada NP possui varias peças. Cada peça possui um status que é aceito, pendente ou rejeitado. Preciso de um query que verifique por NP os status dos itens na condição em que caso o status de todas as peças seja "Aceito" retorna "Verde"; Caso uma ou mais peças esteja como "Pendente" retorna "Amarelo"; Caso uma ou mais peças esteja como "Rejeitado" retorna "Vermelho".

Fiz o seguinte código...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TSJ.NUPROD) AS ProductNumber, 
UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA)) AS Status,
CASE UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA))
      WHEN 'ACEITO' THEN 'Verde'
      WHEN 'PENDENTE' THEN 'Amarelo'
      WHEN 'REJEITADO' THEN 'Vermelho'
      END AS ColorStatus
FROM DB2ADMIN.T7C T7C 
JOIN DB2ADMIN.TTQ TTQ ON T7C.COSITU = TTQ.STATUS
JOIN DB2ADMIN.TSJ TSJ ON T7C.TIUTIL = TSJ.TIUTIL
AND T7C.NUMPSE = TSJ.NUMPSE AND SUBSTR(T7C.NUCHAM, 3, 6) = TSJ.NUMSEQ AND SUBSTR(T7C.NUCHAM, 1, 2) = TSJ.COLIMO
LEFT JOIN  DB2ADMIN.TABACEFORAF FORN ON T7C.TIUTIL = FORN.TIUTIL AND FORN.COFORN = T7C.COFORN
WHERE T7C.TICHAM = 'RAS' AND CAST(DAENTR AS DATE) >= '2018-01-01' 
AND CAST(TSJ.DAPROD AS DATE) <= '2022-01-01'
```

Este é resultado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso de uma query que verifique todos os itens e exiba um resultado único por NP, algo como apenas a segunda linha da imagem.

Comment: Não seria a segunda ? Mais "grave" ? Eu pensaria uma query interna contando os casos a externa trataria a existência dos casos.

Comment: Isso, seria a segunda. Obrigado pela observação. Seria algo como um select e depois um if na externa?

Comment: Sim , um case externo , uma vez fiz algo parecido usando uma function , a function tem um cursor e trata o caso mais grave , mas dá por sql puro também.

Answer (score -1):

Algo assim (sem teste , pronto para negativações ...) :

```
SELECT PRODUCTNUMBER,        
       STATUS,
       (CASE WHEN (VERMELHOS >= AMARELOS OR
                   VERMELHOS >= VERDES THEN 'VERMELHO'
             WHEN AMARELOS >= VERDES THEN 'AMERELO'
             ELSE 'VERDE' END) COR
FROM
(SELECT TRIM(TSJ.NUPROD) AS PRODUCTNUMBER,        
        UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA)) AS STATUS,
        SUM(CASE UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA))
              WHEN 'ACEITO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) VERDES,
        SUM(CASE UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA))
              WHEN 'PENDENTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AMARELOS,
        SUM(CASE UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA))
              WHEN 'REJEITADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) VERMELHOS
FROM DB2ADMIN.T7C T7C 
JOIN DB2ADMIN.TTQ TTQ ON T7C.COSITU = TTQ.STATUS
JOIN DB2ADMIN.TSJ TSJ ON T7C.TIUTIL = TSJ.TIUTIL
AND T7C.NUMPSE = TSJ.NUMPSE AND SUBSTR(T7C.NUCHAM, 3, 6) = TSJ.NUMSEQ AND SUBSTR(T7C.NUCHAM, 1, 2) = TSJ.COLIMO
LEFT JOIN  DB2ADMIN.TABACEFORAF FORN ON T7C.TIUTIL = FORN.TIUTIL AND FORN.COFORN = T7C.COFORN
WHERE T7C.TICHAM = 'RAS' AND CAST(DAENTR AS DATE) >= '2018-01-01' 
AND CAST(TSJ.DAPROD AS DATE) <= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY TRIM(TSJ.NUPROD) ,        
     UPPER(TRIM(TTQ.DENSTA))) VIRTUAL
```